# How to instantiate a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++14

Lets say I have the follow code

```
template<class MemberFunc>
class Foo {
  MyClass object_;
  void call() {
    auto ptr = MemberFunc{};
    (object_.*ptr)();
  }
};


int main() {
  Foo<decltype(&MyClass::doThings)> foo;
  foo.call();
}
```

This code does crash for me because ptr is 0. Why does the member function constructor returns 0?

My workaround is the following but it involves code duplication. Is there no other way to just construct/instantiate the member function from the type? C++14 welcome.

```
template<class MemberFunc, MemberFunc f> 
class Foo {
  MyClass object_;
  void call() {
    (object_.*f)();
  }
};


int main() {
  Foo<decltype(&MyClass::doThings), &MyClass::doThings> foo;
  foo.call();
}
```

Comment: I don't even understand why the first snippet compiles. Pointer-to-member functions are non-type template parameters, hence it shouldn't work with `class` in the template declaration.

Comment: @vsoftco `decltype` yields a type

Comment: @krzaq I missed the `decltype`, good point, thanks! Now funny thing: gcc 6 does not compile the code, complains about "incomplete type" of `ptr`, live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18fedddf9772a87e). Clang 3.7 on the other hand compiles it, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0e77eeefdc2a4ec) (of course as mentioned in the answers it crashes).

Comment: `#define make_foo(func) Foo<decltype(func), func>()` then `auto foo = make_foo(&MyClass::doThings)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the member function constructor returns 0?

Because it's a pointer ([-to-member-function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions)), and *all* scalar types value-initialize to 0 (C++14 [dcl.init]/8.4).

> Is there no other way to just construct/instantiate the member function from the type?

You can have multiple member functions with the same signature; how would it know which member function you want to refer to?

The code you have is fine for C++14. In C++17, it can be shortened to the following:

```
template<auto f> 
class Foo {
  MyClass object_;
  void call() {
    (object_.*f)();
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<&MyClass::doThings> foo;
  foo.call();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know by doing decltype(&MyClass::doThings) I do not erase the actual type of the member function. This is what std::function does, but this it not happening here. So the compiler does know which member function it is.

Comment: @AlexanderTheißen : The type of `decltype(&MyClass::doThings)` is a [pointer-to-member-function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions). It will retain the _signature_ (the return type, parameter types, and const-ness of `doThings`), but it will not retain the _value_ (which member function with that signature is being referred to). I would give you concrete examples demonstrating what I mean if you showed what `MyClass::doThings` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate a member function from its type. For example, consider the following class:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar(int){}
    void baz(int){}
};
```

Suppose you have a type `void (foo::*)(int)`. Which function would you like to get from it?

As of C++1z, you'll be able to use `auto` to deduce non-type, non-template template parameters:

```
template<auto f> 
class Foo {
  MyClass object_;
  void call() {
    (object_.*f)();
  }
};


int main() {
  Foo<&MyClass::doThings> foo;
  foo.call();
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LiGboi8rdUQP5BVR)

---

The only workaround for C++11/14 I can think of is using a macro:

```
#define type_value_pair(x) decltype(x), x
template<class MemberFunc, MemberFunc f> 
class Foo {
  MyClass object_;
  void call() {
    (object_.*f)();
  }
};


int main() {
  Foo<type_value_pair(&MyClass::doThings)> foo;
  foo.call();
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/j5DL3bgaPdiGdxcQ)

But I'd advise against using this, for readability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

`decltype` returns the type of its argument. Using the following example:

```
class MyClass {

public:
    int foo();
    int bar();
};
```

Both

```
decltype(&MyClass::foo);
```

and

```
decltype(&MyClass::bar);
```

is the same type: `int (MyClass::*)()`.

When you default-initialize this type, the default initialization results in a `nullptr`. Hence the crash.

Answer (score 0):

When you value-initialize a pointer to member-function, you will receive a nullptr, of course.

By the way, you can have multiple member function with the same type as you can see in Sam's answer.

I don't know why do you need to put the `MemberFunc` to template parameter list of `Foo`.

However, if you want to make a function to call it, this maybe a better approach in C++ before C++1z (use `auto` in C++1z is better match for this question):

```
class Foo {
  MyClass object_;
public:
  template<class MemberFunc>
  void call(MemberFunc ptr) {
    (object_.*ptr)();
  }
};
int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.call(&MyClass::doThings);
}
```