# Incomplete type error under gcc, should not be the case

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, incomplete-type

This question is related to a recent one on SO: [How to instantiate a member function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40704924/3093378)

The code below

```
struct MyClass {void doThings() {}};

template<class MemberFunc>
struct Foo {
    MyClass object_;
    void call() {
        auto ptr = MemberFunc{};
        (object_.*ptr)();
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<decltype(&MyClass::doThings)> foo;
    foo.call();
}
```

should (imo) compile, although it will cause a segfault due to dereferencing a null-initialized pointer to function member. The answers to the linked question explain why the segfault and how to fix it. However, I don't understand why the code **does not** compile under gcc 6.2, with the compiler spitting the error

> error: 'MemberFunc ptr' has incomplete type in auto ptr = MemberFunc{};

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18fedddf9772a87e)

There is no incomplete type here, `MemberFunc` is fully defined when the compiler performs the template instantiation.

Clang 3.7 on the other hand compiles it (and segfaults as expected), see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0e77eeefdc2a4ec).

Comment: Seems to only occur when you use the brace syntax. `MemberFunc()` works fine.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Smells like a bug then.

Comment: Similar error with a [variable template](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e345727e8e5f5928) and a "cannot convert" error with a [data member declaration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41cd5158e61a657a). Yup it's a bug.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks! Do you want to fill it? If not, I'll do it later today.

Comment: the problem occurs only for member functions, with member fields compiler acts as expected [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nk8w5Vl0HOxj6voR)

Comment: @W.F. Thanks, it's probably a funky parsing error.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ok, then I'll use your code snippets when reporting the bug (if that's OK with you), as they are minimal.

Comment: @vsoftco That's fine

Comment: [This](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NdDjG4KfxaWQsG6n) one causes internal error...

Comment: @W.F. Ohh boy... Yeah this is a bug for sure.